# Altium error when simulating diode

Tags: simulation, altium, error

I have a rather simple circuit and would like to have it simulated. It uses a Schottky diode from the Misc Devices.IntLib, but it keeps giving me an error. It looks like the .nsx is using incorrect syntax / unrecognised parameter:

[image]

Does anyone know why `t_measured` is invalid or why it is generated?

Comment: What does Altium say about it?

Comment: They haven't been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that t_measured is not supported by Altium's flavour of SPICE (XSpice). See [this](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/AMSE/Support+for+PSpice+Models+in+Altium+Designer) reference.

[image]

[Here](http://www2.engr.arizona.edu/~brew/ece304spr07/UserManuals/Temperature%20Dependence.pdf) is a PSPICE explanation:

[image]

Altium has fairly good support for their licensed users.

Comment: He posted the very same question in the Altium forums but hasn't received an answer so far :-(